# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property authManager has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, auth, android-vksdk

Авторизую пользователя через вк командой `VK.login(this, arrayListOf(VKScope.EMAIL, VKScope.WALL))`

Запускаю приложение, в момент попытки войти через вк, компилятор выдаёт ошибку `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property authManager has not been initialized`

Причём ранее данная процедура работала, но после этого в репозитории произошёл конфликт файлов и что-то (???) удалилось
Хотелось бы услышать предположения, в чём может быть причина

Зависимости проекта:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.2.0'
implementation 'com.vk:android-sdk-core:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.vk:android-sdk-api:3.1.0'
```

}

**UPD: ошибка ссылается на внутренний код вк сдк, стектрейс ниже**
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.webiki.bucketlist, PID: 27685                                                                                                    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property authManager has not been initialized
at com.vk.api.sdk.VK.login(VK.kt:85)
at com.webiki.bucketlist.activities.LoginActivity$onCreate$2$1.invoke(LoginActivity.kt:88)
at com.webiki.bucketlist.activities.LoginActivity$onCreate$2$1.invoke(LoginActivity.kt:82)
at com.webiki.bucketlist.activities.MainActivity$Companion.createModalWindow$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:206)
at com.webiki.bucketlist.activities.MainActivity$Companion.$r8$lambda$4NAu51EvctFhYF4g3-j71usykRw(Unknown Source:0)
at com.webiki.bucketlist.activities.MainActivity$Companion$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7590)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7567)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29724)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:223)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:324)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8382)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1059)

Ну и, собственно, единственный мой кусок кода, куда ссылается ошибка

```
vkLogInButton.setOnClickListener {
        MainActivity.createModalWindow(
            this,
            getString(R.string.vpnAttention),
            "Хорошо",
            "Отмена",
            {
                VK.login(this, arrayListOf(VKScope.EMAIL, VKScope.WALL))
            },
            { })
    }
```

Comment: Здесь не приветствуются скрины того, что можно скопировать текстом. И трассировку ошибки добавьте полностью. Похоже что вы пропустили какую-то инициализацию библиотеки

Comment: Собственно зависимость у вас странная. https://dev.vk.com/sdk/android#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%20Maven

Comment: @woesss поправил вопрос, добавил по-нормальному зависимости из доки, всё равно та же ошибка(

Comment: @woesss ошибка была на невнимательности, во время сбоя удалился файл, содержащий айдишник приложения

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в том, что в ресурсы проекта не был добавлен файл с указанием айдишника приложения

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <integer name="com_vk_sdk_AppId">51****92</integer>
</resources>
```